# Can I use user defined function in Xquery to replace node value in PLSQL?

Tags: oracle, plsql, xmltype, qxmlquery

I want to change oracle xmltype node value by my function **my_calculator** but I can't.
See there:

```
set serveroutput on
declare
w_xml xmltype;
begin

SELECT
      XMLQUERY('copy $tmp := .
               modify
                (for $l3 in $tmp//Line3
                    return replace value of node $l3 with my_calculator($l3)
                )
                
                return $tmp'
               PASSING xmltype('<Response><Card>
    <Address attr_cust="0">
      <Line2>def</Line2>
      <Line3>10</Line3>
      <Line4>jkl</Line4>
      <Line5>mno</Line5>
      <Country/>
    </Address>
  </Card>
  <Card>
    <Address attr_cust="0">
      <Line2>def</Line2>
      <Line3>12</Line3>
      <Line4>jkl</Line4>
      <Line5>mno</Line5>
      <Country/>
    </Address>
  </Card>
</Response>') RETURNING CONTENT)
        into w_xml
        FROM dual;
        dbms_output.put_line( w_xml.extract('/*').getClobVal() );
end;
```

It return:

```
Error report -
ORA-19237: XPST0017 - unable to resolve call to function - fn:my_calculator
ORA-06512: at line 5
19237. 00000 -  "XPST0017 - unable to resolve call to function - %s:%s"
*Cause:    The name and arity of the function call given could not be matched with any in-scope function in the static context.
*Action:   Fix the name of the function or the number of parameters to match the list of in-scope functions.
```

Can I use a user's function in "return replace value of node $l3 with my_calculator($l3)" ?
Many thanks.

Comment: Show us your function's code text

Comment: It''s simple function:
create or replace FUNCTION my_calculator( orig_value INT) RETURN INT
IS
BEGIN
RETURN orig_value + 100;
END;

Answer (score 2):

You can't call pl/sql functions in xpath and xquery. They have own functions and operators: https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/
But you can declare and use own xquery function:

```sql
SELECT
      XMLQUERY('declare function local:my_calculator($p) {xs:decimal($p + 100)}; (: eof :)
      copy $tmp := .
               modify
                (for $l3 in $tmp//Line3
                    return replace value of node $l3 with (local:my_calculator($l3))
                )
                return $tmp'
               PASSING xmltype('<Response><Card>
    <Address attr_cust="0">
      <Line2>def</Line2>
      <Line3>10</Line3>
      <Line4>jkl</Line4>
      <Line5>mno</Line5>
      <Country/>
    </Address>
  </Card>
  <Card>
    <Address attr_cust="0">
      <Line2>def</Line2>
      <Line3>12</Line3>
      <Line4>jkl</Line4>
      <Line5>mno</Line5>
      <Country/>
    </Address>
  </Card>
</Response>') RETURNING CONTENT) as xdata
FROM dual;
```

Results:

```
XDATA
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<Response>
  <Card>
    <Address attr_cust="0">
      <Line2>def</Line2>
      <Line3>110</Line3>
      <Line4>jkl</Line4>
      <Line5>mno</Line5>
      <Country/>
    </Address>
  </Card>
  <Card>
    <Address attr_cust="0">
      <Line2>def</Line2>
      <Line3>112</Line3>
      <Line4>jkl</Line4>
      <Line5>mno</Line5>
      <Country/>
    </Address>
  </Card>
</Response>
```

But in this simple case you don't even need PL/SQL functions, just use simple operators:

```sql
SELECT
      XMLQUERY('copy $tmp := .
               modify
                (for $l3 in $tmp//Line3
                    return replace value of node $l3 with (xs:integer($l3) + 100)
                )
                
                return $tmp'
               PASSING xmltype('<Response><Card>
    <Address attr_cust="0">
      <Line2>def</Line2>
      <Line3>10</Line3>
      <Line4>jkl</Line4>
      <Line5>mno</Line5>
      <Country/>
    </Address>
  </Card>
  <Card>
    <Address attr_cust="0">
      <Line2>def</Line2>
      <Line3>12</Line3>
      <Line4>jkl</Line4>
      <Line5>mno</Line5>
      <Country/>
    </Address>
  </Card>
</Response>') RETURNING CONTENT) as xdata
FROM dual;
```

Results:

```
XDATA
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<Response>
  <Card>
    <Address attr_cust="0">
      <Line2>def</Line2>
      <Line3>110</Line3>
      <Line4>jkl</Line4>
      <Line5>mno</Line5>
      <Country/>
    </Address>
  </Card>
  <Card>
    <Address attr_cust="0">
      <Line2>def</Line2>
      <Line3>112</Line3>
      <Line4>jkl</Line4>
      <Line5>mno</Line5>
      <Country/>
    </Address>
  </Card>
</Response>
```

Comment: Thank you. But we want use funtion to transform data. I think I will use updatexml function with multipe nodes .

Comment: Ping me tomorrow and I will show you another way how to use pl/sql functions to replace nodes

Comment: Can you send me an example?

Answer (score 0):

Because I can not use user function in xquery. So I change my code to use updatexml, It will running ok if the data isn't too large and the DB version in 11,12:

```
create or replace FUNCTION fn_xmlupdate( var_xpath VARCHAR2, var_rec XMLTYPE,var_attribute varchar2 default 'text()') RETURN XMLTYPE
IS
v_return xmltype;
querystring varchar2(4000);
update_xquery varchar2(200):='$i/text()';
update_query clob;

BEGIN
if  var_attribute!= 'text()' then
    update_xquery:='$i/attribute::*';
end if;
querystring:='for $i in $doc'||var_xpath||'/descendant-or-self::*
            let $path := $i/string-join(ancestor-or-self::*/name(.), ''/'')
            return <data>{attribute path {concat($path,if (exists($i/attribute::*/name(.))) then 
            concat("[@",$i/attribute::*/name(.),"=",$i/attribute::*,"]","/'||var_attribute||'") else())}, attribute value {'||update_xquery||'}}</data>' ;
            
--dbms_output.put_line(querystring);

select --listagg(path_value,',') within group (order by rownum) update_query 
'select updatexml(:var_rec,'||listagg(path_value,',') within group (order by rownum)||')
from dual '
into  update_query
from
(select ''''||xpath||''','|| MY_TRANSFORM(text) path_value
from   
       XMLTable( 
         querystring
         PASSING var_rec AS "doc"
         COLUMNS xpath varchar2(4000) path '/data/@path', 
                 text  varchar2(4000) path '/data/@value'
       )
);
--dbms_output.put_line(update_query);

execute immediate update_query  into v_return using var_rec;


RETURN v_return;
END;
```

If you want update note value:

```
 fn_xmlupdate(path,xmltype)
```

If you want update attribue value

```
fn_xmlupdate(path,xmltype,@attribute_name)
```